# jquery animate complete using promise calling twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In my jquery-plugin, after completing an animation, i am getting called "destroy" function twice.. any one correct me the wrongs what i do?

function:

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    $.fn.BackendProcess = function(){

        var that = this;

        destroy = function(){
            console.log(arguments.callee.caller.toString());//consoling 2 times
        }

            that.bind( "myEventStart", function( e ) {
                $(this).css({width:"500"});
            });

            that.bind( "myEventEnd", function( e ) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(that).animate({width :"100"},{
                        easing: 'swing',
                        duration:2000
                    }).promise().done(function(){destroy()});

                })
            });

        return{
            start:function(){
                that.trigger("myEventStart");
            },
            stop:function(){
                that.trigger("myEventEnd");
            },
            destroy:function(){
                console.log("distroy starts");
            }


        }
    }
})( jQuery, window , document );

$(".myButton").BackendProcess().start();
$(".myButton").BackendProcess().stop();
```

[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PqH4x/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Frederic pointed out you have got design issue with events. You can fix it by using `on/off` instead `bind` as shown in code below. It removes all the duplicate events by turning them off at initialisation.

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PqH4x/2/)

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    $.fn.BackendProcess = function(){

        var that = this;

        that.off();

        destroy = function(){
            console.log(arguments.callee.caller.toString());
        }

            that.on( "myEventStart", function( e ) {
                $(this).css({width:"500"});
            });

            that.on( "myEventEnd", function( e ) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(that).animate({width :"100"},{
                        easing: 'swing',
                        duration:2000
                    }).promise().done(function(){destroy()});

                })
            });

        return{
            start:function(){
                that.trigger("myEventStart");
            },
            stop:function(){
                that.trigger("myEventEnd");
            },
            destroy:function(){
                console.log("distroy starts");
            }


        }
    }
})( jQuery, window , document );

$(".myButton").BackendProcess().start();
$(".myButton").BackendProcess().stop();
```

Comment: But it will not fix my issue, reason is while i start i should show a preloader agian on event end, i need to show another element to visible.

Comment: works fine. can you give some clue to understand what is happening exactly here..?

Comment: Sure, basically we are removing all events on initialisation, it helps us removing duplicate events.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding handlers to `myEventStart` and `myEventEnd` every time `$.fn.BackendProcess()` is called.

Since you're calling it twice, the same handler is bound twice to `myEventEnd`, so two animations are performed in parallel, resulting in two different promises, and two calls to `console.log()`.

You will have to modify your design so the handlers are only bound once, even if `$.fn.BackendProcess()` is called multiple times.

Comment: Sounds great. can you give me some sample. or demo please?